# Facebook graph API not getting images

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook graph API.
By using this am getting timeline posts `/me/home` .

I am trying to display timeline photos by using object_id.

For this used like this

http://graph.facebook.com/791355974262876/picture?type=normal

But, `Friends updated profile picture or they added photos` are redirect to this image link.

https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yA/r/gPCjrIGykBe.gif

Why I am not getting images. How can solve this issue.

**EDIT :**

Here is me post response

```
{
    actions =     (
                {
            link = "https://www.facebook.com/100001654426439/posts/791354350929705";
            name = Comment;
        },
                {
            link = "https://www.facebook.com/100001654426439/posts/791354350929705";
            name = Like;
        }
    );
    application =     {
        id = 2305272732;
        name = Photos;
    };
    "created_time" = "2014-10-17T07:55:49+0000";
    from =     {
        id = 100001654426439;
        name = "Savad Kunnath";
    };
    icon = "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif";
    id = "100001654426439_791354350929705";
    likes =     {
        count = 3;
        data =         (
                        {
                id = 100000924318296;
                name = "Anoop Haridas";
            },
                        {
                id = 100003006130969;
                name = "Ali Bhai MK";
            },
                        {
                id = 100001875169841;
                name = "Shab\U0258\U0258r Muhamd";
            }
        );
    };
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=791355974262876&set=a.104268106305003.7193.100001654426439&type=1&relevant_count=1";
    "object_id" = 791355974262876;
    picture = "https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/l/t1.0-9/p130x130/10703518_791355974262876_932547360902961732_n.jpg?oh=6b4d7cee37a9c4277f8fc98e7ce99150&oe=54AE46EE";
    privacy =     {
        value = "";
    };
    story = "Savad Kunnath changed his profile picture.";
    "story_tags" =     {
        0 =         (
                        {
                id = 100001654426439;
                length = 13;
                name = "Savad Kunnath";
                offset = 0;
                type = user;
            }
        );
    };
    type = photo;
    "updated_time" = "2014-10-17T07:55:49+0000";
}
```

Comment: When mark down the question please comment the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the ID is a valid user id?

Comment: not user id , i want to get the image from the object_id (imageId)

Comment: What is your response for /me/home? The way you do it now, it looks to me like you want to display the user's profile picture.

Comment: When mark down the question please comment the reason